# Error in logic PHP / SQL Server

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, logic

I have a logic error I cannot for the life of me figure out. The problem is this very very basic login page I have written is always outputting the default answer as opposed the the choice from the table.

I am trying to return to the php the value in `E_Type` in this case the value should return A, however it is not.

What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
<?php
$server   = -Removed;
$login    = -Removed;            
$pass     = -Removed;        
$login    = $_POST['login'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$table    = 'USERPASS';
$table2   = 'EMPLOYEES';
$res      = 'q';

$dblink = @mssql_connect(-Removed) or die("Error 1");
mssql_select_db('group5', $dblink) or die( "unable to select the database");

$sqlquery = "SELECT E_TYPE FROM USERPASS U, EMPLOYEES E WHERE U.EMPLOYEE_ID = E.EMPLOYEE_ID AND PASSWORD = '$password' AND USERNAME = '$login'";
$res = mssql_query($sqlquery, $dblink) or die("Error5");
$count = mssql_num_rows($res);

if($count==1)
{
    if ($res == "A" )
    {
        echo "Success 1";
    }
    else if ($res == "B" )
    {
        echo "Success 2";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error...";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do, explain in 1 line

Comment: What's the output of this script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fetch the result first. In `$res` you basically only have a result handle that can iterate over the results.

Use [`mssql_fetch_assoc`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-fetch-assoc.php) to fetch the results and access them (this would loop over all resulting rows):

```
while(($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($res)) !== FALSE) {
    echo $row['E_TYPE'];
}
```

In your case (if you only expect a single row) use this:

```
if($count == 1) {
    $row = mssql_fetch_assoc($res);
    if ($row['E_TYPE'] == "A" )
    {
        echo "Success 1";
    }
    else if ($row['E_TYPE'] == "B" )
    {
        echo "Success 2";
    }
    else {
        echo "Error...";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`mssql_query` return MS SQL result set, to get returned value, you have to fetch row from this resultset first. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-fetch-assoc.php and other mssql_fetch functions

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$server = -Removed;
$login = -Removed;           
$pass = -Removed;        
$login=$_POST['login'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$table= 'USERPASS';
$table2='EMPLOYEES';
$res='q';

$dblink = @mssql_connect(-Removed) or die("Error 1");
mssql_select_db('group5', $dblink) or die( "unable to select the database");
$sqlquery = "SELECT E_TYPE FROM USERPASS U, EMPLOYEES E WHERE U.EMPLOYEE_ID = E.EMPLOYEE_ID AND PASSWORD = '$password' AND USERNAME = '$login'";
$res = mssql_query($sqlquery, $dblink) or die("Error5");
$count=mssql_num_rows($res);
    if(1 == $count){
        $row=mssql_fetch_assoc($res);//fetch row from database
        switch($row['E_TYPE']) {
            case "A":
                echo "Success 1"; 
                break;
            case "B":
                echo "Success 2"; 
                break;
            default:
                echo "Error..."; 
                break;
        }
    }
}
mssql_free_result($res);
?>
```

you should learn about select...case statements.
only thing I can see is the case of your characters.  databases may or may not be case sensitive.
you are also missing something which can sometimes affect your results:  mysql_free_result().
you should usually do a while statement with regards to fetching rows rather than an if, because there may be more than 1 row.

I usually put the constant before the comparison operator  and the variable on the right side when it's possible and it makes sense, because the compiler will catch the error if in any case it becomes an assignment because of a missing =.